# Finding List of Key Names in MongoDB Query or with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, mongodb-query

```
{
    "Name": {
        "Year": {
            "Model": {
                "SubModel": {
                    "Category": {
                        "SubCategory": [
                            {
                                "firstline": "Value1",
                                "secondline": "Value2"
                            },
                            {
                                "firstline": "Value3",
                                "secondline": "Value4"
                            },
                            {
                                "firstline": "Value5",
                                "secondline": "Value6"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
.....
.....
```

I have a JSON data like this and I can insert this data in MongoDB.

Now can i get the list of "Name", list of "Year" under a "Name",
list of "Model" under a "Year", list of "SubModel" under a "Model", list of "Category" under a "Submodel" and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDb you can access you documents just as you access a JSON object. Suppose you want get the list of subcategory of a certain collection. Try like this:

```
db.getCollection('NewCollection').findOne({_id:'some Object Id'})['Name']['Year']['Model']['SubModel']['Category']['SubCategory']
```

Answer (score 1):

with the help of @rashik-hasnat, I want to add these to list the key names only:

```
var data = db.getCollection('NewCollection').findOne({_id:'some Object Id'})['Name']['Year']['Model']['SubModel']['Category']['SubCategory'];

for (var key in data){
    print(key);
}
```